# Too many arguments in method signature in class file sc while deploying ksql stream

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to deploy ksql stream using ksql CLI. FOr some reason I am unable to share my exact ksql stream. But while deploying the stream it gives me below error:

```
Too many arguments in method signature in class file SC
```

I have written 2 ksql streams. One stream on a kafka topic and other stream is this one which is reading data from previous stream and adding new columns in the json and putting it to new kafka topic. In my ksql stream I have written case statements in which I am checking the length of an array and based on the length of array I am creating an array of struct. This array contains 8 elements. But when I remove 2 elements from the array, ksql stream is deployed successfully but when I add the elements again and try and deploy it gives me the above error.

Any reason why this error is coming. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a Java error. What versions of ksql server and client are you using?

Comment: both the versions are 6.1.1

Comment: Have you tried reporting this issue in ksql github or Confluent forums?

Comment: This error seems to be related to the actual source code. You'll get a more direct answer at least from the ksql developers on Github